# fill color of confidence bands in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to change my confidence bands to the same color as my regression lines but I am currently stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A reproducible example would be good: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `aes(fill=as.factor(numbers)))` rather than `fill=aes(as.factor(numbers))`

Answer (score 3):

You can check this code that can be useful. I have used new dataset `penguins`. As Dr. Bolker said, be careful about the `color` and `fill` options in your `aes()`. As no data was included I tried to replicate your colors and shading style:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
#Code for plot
ggplot(penguins, aes(x=bill_length_mm, y=flipper_length_mm,
                     color=species,fill = species)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm,alpha=0.2)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","gold","brown"))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","gold","brown"))
```

Output:

[image]